Prove that of all triangles having same base and equal areas, the isosceles triangle has the least perimeter.
I wrote a mathematical proof proving this statement. I want to confirm that I haven't assumed anything in the proof. I'd be grateful to anyone who confirms this or points out if I assumed anything.

TO PROVE: perimeter of $\triangle ABC <$ perimeter of  $\triangle BCD$

GIVEN:
Let two triangles, $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta DBC$ which have the same base BC and have the same area.
If two triangles lie on the same base and have equal areas, then they must lie between the same parallels.
CONSTRUCTION: Draw a line l through A and D parallel to BC.
Then, produce BA to a point P such that AP = AB; then draw a circle $\omega_0$ passing through P, B $\land$ C, taking A as the center.
Afterwards, produce BD to a point R such that DR = DC
Then, construct another circle $\omega_1$ passing through P, R and C, taking D as center. $\omega_1$ intersects BP in Q. Join P to R. $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ are always achievable as there is one and only one circle passing through three non collinear points.

PROOF:
Now, the points H and J as marked in the diagram are the end points of the diameter of $\omega_1$. 
$\implies$ arc HJ is a semicircle

$\implies$ length of arc QR is greater than the length of a semicircle.
Now, angle subtended by a semicircle is a right angle.
$\implies$ angle subtended by arc QR on the circle is an obtuse angle. 
$\implies$ $\angle QPR$ > $\frac{\pi}{2}$
$\implies$ $\angle BPR$ > $\frac{\pi}{2}$                        ... (i)
In $\triangle BPR$, by angle sum property,
$\angle PBR + \angle BPR + \angle  BRP = \pi$
Now, from (i), $\angle BPR > \frac{\pi}{2}$
$\implies$ $\angle PBR + \frac{\pi}{2} + \angle  BRP < \pi$
$\implies$ $\angle PBR + \angle  BRP < \frac{\pi}{2}$
$\implies$ $\angle PBR < \frac{\pi}{2}$ $\land$ $\angle  BRP < \frac{\pi}{2}$
$\implies$ $\angle PBR < \angle BPR$ $\land$ $\angle  BRP < \angle BPR$ $\quad\quad$ (An acute angle is less than both a right angle and an obtuse angle)
$\implies$ $PR < BR \land BP < BR$ $\quad\quad$(By Triangle Inequality)
$\implies BP < BR$
$\implies BA + AP < BD + DR$
$\implies BA + BA < BD + CD$ $\quad\quad$ $(AP = AB \land DR = CD)$ (By construction)
$\implies BA + AC < BD + CD$ $\quad\quad$ $(AB = AC, as \triangle ABC$ is isosceles)
$\implies BA + AC + BC < BD + CD + BC$
Hence, Proved.
Thank you in advance to anyone who confirms the legitimacy of this proof.

You are complicating things too much:
If $AB$ is fixed, all triangles with the same area must have its third point on line $p$ parallel to AB. The point $E$ completes isosceles triangle $ABE$. Find a reflection point $B'$ of $B$ with respect to line $p$. Obivously $EB=EB'$. But also note that:
$$\angle AEB'=\angle AEB + \angle BEF + \angle FEB'=\angle AEB + 2\angle BEF=\angle AEB+2\angle ABE = 180^o$$
So points $A,E,B'$ are on the same line. Circumference of the triangle is actually: $AB+AE+BE=AB+AE+EB'=AB+AB'$. For any other triangle, like $ABF$, circumference is equal to $AB+AF+BF=AB+AF+FB'$. This circumference is obviously longer because $AF+FB'\gt AB'$

this is a fine proof but the questioner asked for verification of their proof, not proof of the statement (I added the solution-verification tag to the question just now)
